# Why won't this extremely simple Javascript code work?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function f1()
{
    document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML="<audio src=\"2.wav\" autoplay> </audio>";

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="f1()" value="Playyy!" />
<span id="test2">
</span>


</body>
</html>
```

I have also uploaded the code with the file 2.wav that it uses over here:
http://aafe6m96.facebook.joyent.us/test1.html

Comment: What result were you expecting?

Comment: It would help if you'd describe exactly what you mean by it not working.

Comment: Firebug says: Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindow.alert]
[Break On This Error]  

alert();

Comment: Remove the `alert()` call or pass in something (e.g. `"0"`)

Comment: @IsisCode
What I am expecting is that the audio clip 2.wav must play when I click the button. Tell me if that's not right.

Comment: @Pointy Check the comment above. That's what I want it to happen but isn't happening.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Could you please see my comment on Daniel's answer mate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't kill yourself yet. Try this first:

```
document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML='<audio src="2.wav" autoplay> </audio>';
```

That is: no escapes and no hipsals, in HTML they are unknown.

If this wont help, create a new `audio`-element into your document.

```
newAudio=document.getElementById('test2').appendChild(document.createElement('AUDIO'));
newAudio.src='2.wav';
newAudio.autoplay=true;
```

Comment: None of those worked, but thank you for pointing me to technique#2.
I tried this and it worked on IE9:
`newAudio=document.getElementById('test2').appendChild(document.createElement('EMBED'));
newAudio.hidden=true;
newAudio.src='2.wav';
newAudio.start=true;
newAudio.play();`

Though it still doesn't work with Chrome. Apparently chrome doesn't work well with embed tags.

Answer (score 4):

The error message you are getting is saying that for `alert` you must pass one parameter.

Comment: It seems that this error appears only in FF, other browsers show an empty alert-box.

Comment: I would have killed myself if that would have worked!
As @Teemu said, it just simply shows up a blank alert box. Don't think that's an issue.

Anyway, I've altered the code on the same page. Still doesn't work. Check the link again.
This is SO FRUSTRATING! I'm actually working on an assignment for which something like that isn't working, and I've wasted 5hours on that thing.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're tryng to do:

1. Your `alert` is empty, should read something like: 
            
   `alert('Your message here')`
2. Your element should read something like: 
   `document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML="<audio src=\'2.wav\' autoplay>"`

Comment: As mentioned in the comments of my answer, the string value is already escaped :)

Answer (score 0):

are you testing with chrome?  try with an mp3 instead, or with source tags.

in this link you can find compatible formats for each browser http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

Comment: I guess I could try that. But the thing is, I've wasted so many hours on it, I'm desperate to know what's causing this.

Comment: first of all calm down, have a beer hehe. on what browsers have you tested? firefox, chrome, IE? (btw i suggest you remove the empty alert() just because it seems to be misleading others on the real problem youre trying to solve)

Comment: I did remove the empty alert in the file uploaded. I'll remove it from the inline code too. Anyway, I was only working with Chrome as I trust it immensely - rookie mistake. Just a minute ago I tried all the variations of the code that I had tried on Chrome on IE 9 and one of them worked just as I wanted. Look at my comment on Teemu's code for details :)